# requiring old versions of gems

Tags: ruby, sql-server, activerecord

Since none of the tools I have handy on my Windows laptop can export decent CSV files from SQL Server to save their lives, I figured I'd roll my own in a few lines of Ruby.

Because I'm hitting the version of SQL Server from the turn of the century, I have to use an old version of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.  As far as I can tell I'm doing this correctly, and should be using activerecord `~> 2.2.3` and the `2-3-stable` branch of activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, but I am getting an error that complains it is `Unable to activate activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12, because activerecord-2.2.3 conflicts with activerecord (~> 3.2.0)`. Here's my code (without anything specifically related to CSVs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

gem 'activerecord', "~> 2.2.3"
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', github: 'arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :branch => '2-3-stable'

require 'activerecord'
require 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
require 'pry'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlserver",
  :mode => "odbc",
  :username => "c3",
  :password => "92641",
  :dsn => "Connect3"
)
ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix = 'dbo.'

class Dwnld_Hdr < ActiveRecord::Base
end

pry
```

Why is it trying to load `activerecord (~> 3.2.0)` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you might probably use [bundler](http://bundler.io/), because then it will allow you to run the [specific gem sets](http://rakeroutes.com/blog/how-to-use-bundler-instead-of-rvm-gemsets/).

Read [here](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/using-bundler-with-non-rails-ruby.html) and [here](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/bundler-without-rails/) to get an idea on how to use bundler in a non-Rails project.

Comment: I actually tried that first, and [it didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20688914/241142).  I was hoping this approach would be easier than overcoming [the problem I ran into on the normal Gemfile approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20688914/241142).  Of course it's quite possibly having the same problem, but burying it just a little deeper.