# `bundle install` fails (because of git protocol)

Tags: ruby, git, bundler, dtn

With this simple Gemfile,

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'activerecord', "~> 2.2.3"
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', github: 'arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :branch => '2-3-stable'
```

`bundle install` fails with

```
Fetching git://github.com/arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=No error

Git error: command `git clone
"git://github.com/arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git"
"c:/Languages/Ruby/1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-8019982c6a12a1297e8a135275
d94bdee6cd893b"
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory c:/Users/BZISAD0/Code/CSV has failed.
```

At first I thought my proxy configurations were screwed up but I can execute this command with no problem:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git
```

With the git protocol, however, it fails:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git
Cloning into 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error
```

so I'm inferring that the proxy is not playing nice with the git protocol.  At any rate, for whatever reason, http is working fine but the git protocol is not.

Is there a way to work around this?  E.g. configuring the use of `http://` rather than `git://` in my `~/.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use the `github:` short form in your Gemfile, just use the regular `git:` syntax

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', git: 'http://github.com/arthrex/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git'
```