# omniauth gems not installing in china (behind great firewall)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, omniauth, firewall

I'm testing omniauth integration on an app while on a work-related trip in China and am having some issues with my regular ruby workflow.

I have been able to install most gems as per usual, in some odd cases, I had to change my gem source from https://rubygems.org/ to https://ruby.taobao.org (A reliable local mirror of rubygems), but when it comes to installing essentially any omniauth-related gem, I run into trouble.

Typically after putting one in my gemfile, and running bundle nothing happens. The command has no effect. In my gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter', :github => 'arunagw/omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-github', :github => 'intridea/omniauth-github'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
```

Only the twitter gem was able to download, I suppose because it is pulling the code from github (which isn't blocked... although gist.github is). I get the same result no matter whether using a vpn or not. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `bundle install` hang or does it just exit? You don't get any error messages from bundler?

Comment: It just hangs infinitely, neither exiting or turning an error. Today, I went to a friend's office and tried it there and it worked! No problems. I guess it must be my network at home. No idea how to overcome this though.

Comment: It could be that you are behind a proxy which does not allow the `git://` protocol. Try cloning a project from github.

Comment: I think you must be right. I am also unable to git clone. Would you happen to know any workarounds for this?

Comment: I have never had the issue myself but there are few questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688914/bundle-install-fails-because-of-git-protocol